# Updating multiple files to Github via API

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, github-api

I'm trying to create an interface for updating a configuration file, as well as an image file using Github for Dart and flutter. All of the following functions are called when a TextButton is pressed.

The first updates the configuration file with a new base64 encoded string.

The second creates a new text file, with the contents being a base64 image.

The third is implemented in the event that there is already an image with the same name as is trying to be created, and will overwrite that file if needed. - My functions come from the implementation section of the following pages:
https://pub.dev/documentation/github/latest/github/RepositoriesService/createFile.html
https://pub.dev/documentation/github/latest/github/RepositoriesService/updateFile.html

```
 updateFile(RepositorySlug(ownerName,repoName), "assets/config/${configID}Config.yaml", "Update Config File.", base64.encode((createExportString()).codeUnits),configSha);
  createFile(RepositorySlug(ownerName, repoName), CreateFile(branch: "master", message: "Create Image TXT B64",content: base64.encode((imageData.codeUnits)), path: "assets/images/${imageName}.txt"));
  updateFile(RepositorySlug(ownerName, repoName), "assets/images/${imageName}.txt", "Update Image TXT B64 (image already exists).", base64.encode(imageData.codeUnits),imageSha);
```

When I attempt to run this code, only the configuration file will be changed, and not the image.

As these are asynchronous methods I've tried using .whenComplete chained one after another. In this case, the image file was created but the configuration file did not change.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!